# How do I figure out what Issue a file is attached to in JIRA?

Tags: jira

I have a full URL path for a file attachment in our JIRA installation (e.g. /jira/secure/attachment/40226/FileName.jpg). However, I'm not sure what Issue this file is currently attached to, since the attachement URLs don't contain any information about the "parent" issue. Is there any way using JQL to figure out this link? Any plugins that could help?

Comment: Some ideas at https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/53736/search-by-attachment-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the issue from the file location. The attachments are arranged in the following hierarchy:

```
attachments -> project-name -> issue key
```

for example, if Jira is installed at `/var/atlassian/application-data` and the attachments are under `jira/data/attachments`, for issue on project `DVP`, issue `DRP-913`, the attachment will be found at:

```
/var/atlassian/application-data/jira/data/attachments/DVP/DVP-913
```

the path you gave as an example isn't the default attachment path, that's why it doesn't have any information about the parent issue.

Another less effective way would be to [query Jira's DB directly](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACOM/Example+SQL+queries+for+JIRA#ExampleSQLqueriesforJIRA-Findwhichissueanattachmentbelongsto):

```
SELECT * FROM jiraissue WHERE id in 
  (SELECT issueid from changegroup where ID in 
    (SELECT groupid FROM changeitem WHERE NEWVALUE='<enter attachment ID>')
  )
```

you can find more information about the [DB structure here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Database+Schema).

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: The path that Daniel was giving was the **URL** and not the path on the file system; as far as I know there is no way without querying the DB to map those two (and then, as you already pointed out, you can get the information directly).

Comment: @mthomas Ah, that's what I was afraid of. Thanks for confirming it. Seems like something that Atlassian should support.